# Phoenix wraps JSON request in a map with "_json" key

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some issues running tests on a Phoenix controller.
What I want is to supply a list of maps to it, but if I do just that, I get `Argument Error`.

Test code

```
      params =
        [
          %{"id" => 1, "sum" => 6},
          %{"id" => 2, "sum" => 4}
        ]


      conn =
        conn
        |> put(Routes.stat_path(conn, :replace_all), params)
```

The error

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
     code: |> put(Routes.stat_path(conn, :replace_all), params)
     stacktrace:
       (stdlib 4.0.1) :maps.from_list([%{"id" => 1, "sum" => 6}, %{"id" => 2, "sum" => 4}])
       (elixir 1.13.4) lib/enum.ex:1448: Enum.into_map/1
       (plug 1.14.0) lib/plug/adapters/test/conn.ex:161: Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn.body_or_params/4
       (plug 1.14.0) lib/plug/adapters/test/conn.ex:21: Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn.conn/4
       (phoenix 1.6.15) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:236: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch_endpoint/5
       (phoenix 1.6.15) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:225: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/myapp_web/controllers/stat_controller_test.exs:15: (test)
```

I decided to do a small change and encode JSON myself in the tests:

```
params =
        [
          %{"id" => 1, "sum" => 6},
          %{"id" => 2, "sum" => 4}
        ]
        |> Jason.encode!()

      conn =
        conn
        # this line is required for binary data
        |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
        |> put(Routes.stat_path(conn, :replace_all), params)
```

What I get in the controller now is a bit strange. My data is wrapped into a map with `_json` key, so instead of the list (which I need) I get this map:

```
%{"_json" => [%{"id" => 1, "sum" => 6}, %{"id" => 2, "sum" => 4}]}
```

What I'm doing wrong and how to properly test a Phoenix controller in case I want to supply a list of maps into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is [`Plug.Parsers.JSON`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.JSON.html#content).

> `JSON` documents that aren’t maps (arrays, strings, numbers, etc) are parsed into a `"_json"` key to allow proper param merging.

Quoting José from [this answer](https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-wrapping-array-request-inside-json-field/31115/3):

> You cannot [avoid wrapping] because `conn.params` is a map. So if we set it to a `list`, other parts of plug will fail. But the list is stored as is under `_json`. You can also disable `Plug.Parsers.JSON` and roll your own parser.

That said, for this particular request you are to roll on your own parsed.

Comment: I thought that this wrapping would happen only in tests and that worried me, because for my task I need to pass a list of values to the controller. It turns out, that if I just send a request to the app, the same wrapping happens. I need to just wrap params in my controller like this `def replace_all(conn, %{"_json" => params}) do` and no other changes needed.
Thank you for your valuable input regarding parsers and related discussion!

Comment: If the controller is under your control, I’d better use an explicit hand-made wrapping an array into a map like `%{data: […]}` instead of relying on implicit and misleading `_json` embedded by 3rd party.

Comment: I would do just that, but API specs aren't under my control in this task.